# Segmentation error while working with strings

Tags: c, string, segmentation-fault

Given a string, num, consisting of alphabets and digits, find the frequency of each digit(0-9) in the given string.

'''

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<ctype.h>

int main() {

    /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT */ 
    char num[20];
    int i;
    int count[15]={0};
  
    scanf("%s",num);
    

    for(i=0;i<10;i++){
        printf("\n");     
        for(int j=0;j<strlen(num);j++){
            if(isdigit(num[j])){
               if(i == num[j]-'0'){
                count[i]+=1;
            }

            }
           
        }
        printf("\nCount %d:%d",i,count[i]);
    }  

    for(i=0;i<10;i++){
        printf("%d ",count[i]);
    } 
    return 0;
}
```

'''

OUTPUT:

Count 0:5

Count 1:9

Count 2:5

Count 3:12

Count 4:8

Count 5:11

Count 6:15

Count 7:4

Count 8:4

exited, segmentation fault

Why is it not working when checking if the digit is 9?

Comment: `char num[20];` allocates space for 19 characters plus a null terminator, but the printed counts show 73 digits. Whatever input you entered overran the buffer.

Comment: Furthermore, because you print `\n` characters before a line, instead of at the end, as they were designed for, the line with the count for 9 remains in the buffer instead of being printed immediately. The program actually finished those initial loops and had gone on to further code, where it crashed due to the buffer overrun.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Ah, I completely forgot about the size of the string. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When looking at your output, it seems that you have entered a string much longer than 19 characters. So your program has undefined behavior.

This

```
scanf("%s",num);
```

is something that you should never do. Remember to limit the input to the size of your buffer. That is:

```
char num[20];     // Size of buffer is 20

scanf("%19s",num);
        ^^
        At max allow 19 characters so that there is also room for the string termination
```

Or - perhaps better - use `fgets` instead of `scanf`. One benefit of `fgets` is that it takes the buffer size as argument - consequently you never forget to specify it.

Also notice that your outer `for` loop is unnecessary. You can update the array directly using a single loop.

```
// for(i=0;i<10;i++){  Delete this - it's not needed

    for(int j=0;j<strlen(num);j++)
    {
        if(isdigit(num[j]))
        {
            count[num[j]-'0']+=1;  // Update array
        }
    }
```

BTW: You only need 10 elements in the counter, i.e.

```
int count[15]={0};   --->  int count[10]={0};
```

Comment: I would also suggest using `fgets(buffer, BUFSIZE, stdin)` instead of scanf